# Customizing STL iterator class

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

which concept in c++ teaches you to extend and write your own iterator class? I know a little about writing templates.

Comment: What do you mean by "concept"? You write iterators when you need to iterate over a container that doesn't already have suitable iterators, whether that's because the container is non-Standard and needs to be fleshed out, or because you have some bizarre iteration requirements such as transparent filtering, or iterating containers of containers.

Comment: You can have iterators for non-containers too, for instance the ostream iterator. In general, you can define iterators for any logical collection, even if that collection does not exist as an C++ object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SGI Standard Template Library (STL) documentation](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/table_of_contents.html) explains all of the iterator concepts and their relationships.

How you take those concepts and use them to implement an iterator for your own container depends entirely on what kind of container it is and what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking in C++ by Bruce Eckel has a [good explanation](http://nicolas.blancpain.free.fr/Documents/Cpp/onlinev2/Chapter04.html).